# Button title font

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

```
btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Times New Roman", size: 20)
```

I know this is the way to change font size of button. But it does not work for me.

Anybody know why it's not working for me ?

Comment: Provide some context. Where is this code? Show it in relation to other code used to setup the button including setting the button's title.

Comment: your code is absolutely fine, please provide more context

Comment: Provide the context. What does happen? What else are you doing? this single line that you have shown should work as per documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **setAttributedTitle** on button instance fixes the problem

```
let title = "Some String"
    let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString.init(string: title, attributes: [.font: UIFont(name:"Times New Roman", size: 20)!])
    UIButton().setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: .normal)
```

Comment: This is a valid solution but the OP's code is also correct if used at the proper time.